# File Sizes for Rich Media Banners

Tags: banner

Hello I am preparing a Rich Media Banner in Sizmek that expands from 300x250 to 300x600.  In the 300x250 size the banner runs a standard flash add.

My question is does this 300x250 size need to be under the 40kb limit for non RM banners?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

K-size specs are up to the publishers, but yes, most likely you need to keep your collapsed state under 40k. Sizmek adds several kb of their class files, so it's even less than 40k in practice. You may be able to do a 2nd 'polite load' prior to expanding, or sub-load upon user interaction. Check with your media team to get exact specs.